# Unable to copy ip address from string to sockaddr_in

Tags: c, sockets, sockaddr-in

I am trying to copy an IP address from a string to struct sockaddr_in but somehow there's some error popping up.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buf = "128.10.25.102:30015";
    char ip[30];
    struct sockaddr_in s1_addport;
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != ':') i++;
    strncpy(ip, &buf[0], i);
    ip[strlen(ip)] = '\0';

    printf("ip: %s, strlen:%zu\n",ip,strlen(ip));
    inet_aton(ip,&s1_addport.sin_addr);
    printf("Server IP: %s\n",inet_ntoa(s1_addport.sin_addr));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code shows:

```
ip: 128.10.25.102, strlen:13  
Server IP: 0.0.0.0
```

There is some error in copying the value from `ip` string which I am unable to figure out. What could be the reason?

Comment: What error is popping up?

Comment: Have you tried using `inet_pton` instead of `inet_aton`?

Comment: no error is popped. server_IP is shown as 0.0.0.0 instead of 128.10.25.102. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What is the real name of the variable? `s1_addport` or `s3_addport`?

Comment: yeah. i tried inet_pton as well. same error!

Comment: edited the question. It's s3_addport

Comment: i just tried `inet_aton(ip, &(s3_addport.sin_addr));`. Not working again

Comment: If I flesh this code out to a complete, compilable test program, I cannot reproduce the problem. I note that one of the changes I had to make was changing `s3_addport` to `s1_addport` in two places.  It is likely that your _real_ code has similar typos, such that you are writing the address to one `sockaddr_in` and then reading it back from a different one.

Comment: Also, you _really_ should be using [`getaddrinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), which handles IPv6 seamlessly, does DNS lookups, completely fills in sockaddr structures for you, and insulates you from the pointer-aliasing headaches involved with manual operations on `sockaddr_*`, instead of these legacy functions.

Comment: @zwol could you post your code? I would like to check how `ip` string got initialized. thanks

Comment: @re3el http://pastebin.com/zCk8jtY7

Comment: @c650 `&(foo.bar)` and `&foo.bar` have exactly the same behavior.

Comment: @zwol: I am using the below code for ip. Is there anything wrong with this? http://pastebin.com/rPi52XCN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem in your pastebin code:

```
ip[strlen(ip)]='\0';
```

(Trying to append null terminator but using strlen, which itself depends on a null terminator to be present).

Here is the fix:

```
....
while(buf[i]!=':')
    i++;
strncpy(ip,&buf[0],i);
ip[i]='\0';
puts(ip);
....
```